# How to invoke a 3D Flip effect on a timer

Tags: jquery, css, timer, flip

I like this flip code since it keeps the perspective of even HTML tables during the flip animation and it's pure CSS3. I was just wondering how you would approach having this flip on a timer and not on hover.

Here is the JSFiddle I'm working with:

[FLIP ON TIMER - JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/xpancom/wG299/)

It should be a 3 or 4 second timer and will happen on multiple divs so this code could possibly be used:

```
$('.row').each(function(i){
    var row = $(this);
  setTimeout(function() {
          row.toggleClass('flip', !row.hasClass('flip'));
      }, 1500*i);

});
```

I would very much like to know what you feel is the best approach for this. Thanks

Comment: You're approach is correct, you must structure the CSS to match it. And I don't think you'll be able to flip individual rows of the table easily, you'd have to add some HTML elements enveloping each row most likely (so that just the row can flip and not the whole table)

Answer (score 2):

Most probably that's not what you want, but let's make a try :-)
I added that:

```
flip-container:hover .flipper, .flip-container.hover .flipper, #flip-toggle.flip .flipper {
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s 2s;
    transition: transform 1s 2s;
}
```

and the result is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/wG299/7/) (delayed transition on hover; will happen 2 seconds after 2 hover)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers, I ended up going with this:

```
-webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
-moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
transform: rotateY(180deg);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xpancom/wG299/9/